# Is there a function to "zip" two cell arrays together?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Suppose I have a cell array `A` and `B`, as so:

```
A = {'A' 'B' 'C' 'D'};
B = {1 2 3 4 };
```

I wanted to create cell array `C` by "zipping" A and B together, as so:

```
C = zip(A,B)
C = 
    'A' 1 'B' 2 'C' 3 'D' 4
```

Does such a function exist? (Obviously such a function would not be difficult to write, but laziness is a programmer's best friend and if such a function already exists I'd rather use that.)

(I got the idea from Perl, where the [`List::MoreUtils`](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/List-MoreUtils-0.33/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm) package offers the `zip` function that does this. The name comes from the fact that the `zip` function interleaves two lists, like a zipper.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about this:

```
C = [A(:),B(:)].';   %'
D = C(:)
```

returns:

```
D = 

'A'
[1]
'B'
[2]
'C'
[3]
'D'
[4]
```

Comment: +1 Concatenate and transpose are the way to go.

Comment: Those _conjugate_ transposes... :-)